# How I can replace a lost folder in a ExtJS project?

Tags: javascript, extjs, directory, frameworks, directory-structure

I'm having problems with ExtJS-7.0.0 (I have to use it for a job interview test).
I understood that I have to build my web application starting from the sencha cmd and I followed all the procedures written in the sencha doc. 
I noticed that in my projects folder tree, I don't have the view>main>Main folder.
It is possible that when I created the app from the cmd, it didn't loaded this folders in it? What should I do in that case?
It's my first time with this framework and I don't know how to go on.
Thank you for help!

Comment: What is your folder structure? Did you create a classic, modern or universal application? Folder structures are different based on type of app you created. Maybe share your sencha generate app command you sent when creating your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER: Sorry for formatting. First Post here.**

I never had this problem with "sencha -sdk /path/to/ext7 generate app MyApp /path/to/my-app" before if you used that way to generate your app.

But if it's just the base view missing I can give you a workaround.

If you need to create new base views you should look into the "sencha generate view" command in the sencha cmd.
To look at the documentation just use "sencha help generate" and "sencha help generate view"

I hope that helps you.